# Display : None/Block Style Tab Menu Creation with Buttons and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function tab_menu(){ 
  if (buttonObject.value == value){
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

i was trying when click to buttons check Button Value and show a div based on Button's Value and hide others divs it should show just one div at same time. I wonder there is a javascript Master who can solve this problem.

Comment: You are making one div visible but you forgot to make others invisible same time

Comment: Have a look at jQuery UI Tab control http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: -shadow code that i writed just example not working. -John Hartsock Thank you that exactly what i look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCRIPT:

```
function tabmenu(buttonObject){ 
    var value = buttonObject.value
    var target = document.getElementById(value);

    if(target) {
       var siblings = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
       for(i=0;i<siblings.length;i++){
          siblings[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       target.style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="tab1">Tab1</div>
    <div id="tab2">Tab2</div>
    <div id="tab3">Tab3</div>
</div>

<button onclick="tabmenu(this);" value="tab1">Tab1</button>
<button onclick="tabmenu(this);" value="tab2">Tab2</button>
```

1. find the tab to activate (assuming value = tab.id)
2. find the parent and hence it's siblings (assuming they are DIVs)
3. hide the siblings
4. show the target

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/4rWdQ/

Comment: I don't see why you're being downvoted. The question was very vague and your solution tries to add to the little code that was supplied with the question. I think it's way better that "use jQuery UI". jQuery UI is great, but on stack**overflow**, you have to assume that people want to understand things and learn how they work and that is why this is a good answer!

Comment: really awesome jquery was solved my problem but i hate jquery you able to make it with javascript ^_^ i will use your method thank you very much i will vote up you and mark as answer.